# time for division instruction in rh850 assembly

Tags: assembly, devise

I am using rh850 controler.

It has operation for devision DIVQ, The time fro executing this operation is defined as N+7, where

N = (Effective number of bits of absolute value of dividend) – (Effective number of bits of absolute value of
divisor).

I am not sure what is the meaning of "Effective number of bits of absolute value". I check in internet and I found that "Effective number of bits (ENOB) is a measure of the dynamic range of an analog-to-digital converter (ADC) and its associated circuitry." I'm not working with ADC currently. Can Someone explain me how to calculate it.

Comment: Presumably it means how many bits the number really needs, as opposed to how many bits you store it on. Or, in other words, the 1-based position of the highest bit set.

Comment: I also thought this but I was not sure